# JButton array ActionListener value

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
for(gbc.gridy = 3; gbc.gridy > 0; gbc.gridy--)
        for(gbc.gridx = 0; gbc.gridx < 3;gbc.gridx++)
          {
            grid[btnNum] = new JButton("" + (btnNum+1));
            grid[btnNum].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
            frame.add(grid[btnNum], gbc);
            grid[btnNum].addActionListener(this);
            grid[btnNum].addKeyListener(this);
            btnNum++;
          }
```

I have an array of buttons displayed in a 3x3 grid and each one has an action listener.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String output = "";
        if(e.getSource() == grid[0]){
            System.out.println("button 1");
        }
}
```

Is this not correct?

Complete example in context:

```
public class ButtonGrid implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    JFrame frame=new JFrame(); //creates frame
    JButton[] grid; //names the grid of buttons




    public ButtonGrid(){ //constructor
            frame.setTitle("MPC");
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); //set layout
            JButton[] grid=new JButton[12]; //allocate the size of grid

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            int btnNum = 0;

            grid[9] = new JButton("0");
            grid[9].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
            grid[10] = new JButton("-");
            grid[10].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
            grid[11] = new JButton("=");
            grid[11].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
            frame.add(grid[9], gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            frame.add(grid[10], gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            frame.add(grid[11], gbc);

            for(gbc.gridy = 3; gbc.gridy > 0; gbc.gridy--)
                for(gbc.gridx = 0; gbc.gridx < 3;gbc.gridx++){
                    grid[btnNum] = new JButton("" + (btnNum+1));
                    grid[btnNum].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
                    frame.add(grid[btnNum], gbc);
                    grid[btnNum].addActionListener(this);
                    grid[btnNum].addKeyListener(this);
                    btnNum++;
                }
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
            frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ButtonGrid();//makes new ButtonGrid with 2 parameters


    }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String output = "";
        if(e.getSource() == grid[0]){
            System.out.println("button one");
            //playSound(abc.kick);
        }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your grid variable is null in the ActionListener. My bet -- you're shadowing the variable.

Solution: make sure that you initialize the grid field, not a local grid variable

```
public class ButtonGrid implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    JFrame frame=new JFrame(); 
    JButton[] grid; // grid field remains null

    public ButtonGrid(){ 
            frame.setTitle("MPC");
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
            JButton[] grid=new JButton[12]; //  ****** a LOCAL variable ******
```

At the indicated line you create the shadowed variable. This means because you redeclare grid within the constructor, you initialize only the local variable and not the field that was declared in the class leaving the field null. Solution: Don't re-declare grid. Change it to:

```
public class ButtonGrid implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    JButton[] grid; 

    public ButtonGrid(){
            frame.setTitle("MPC");
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
            grid = new JButton[12]; //  ***** this initializes the field ******
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String output = "";
   for(int i=0; i<=grid.length; i++){
       if(e.getSource() == grid[i]){
            System.out.println("button "+i);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I got the same errors with this one too. Basically a list of errors with (Unknown Source)

Comment: @KickButtowski: bingo -- some key missing informaiton

Comment: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ButtonGrid.actionPerformed(ButtonGrid.java:272)"

Comment: @user3562657 which line of your code? can you plz provide more info from your code?

Comment: @user3562657: you're holding back key information. Which line is 272? which line throws the exception? For all we know you could be variable shadowing.

Comment: The line with the for loop for the suggested code, if(e.getsource() == grid[1]) for the original. Same error on each

Comment: why gird[1] not start from gird[0]?

Comment: @user3562657: edit your original post to include all pertinent information, including that this is a NullPointerException and which line is involved. This information is much too critical to be buried in comments. Also show where you initialize the grid variable. I've guessed at an answer because it is impossible to give a definitive answer yet without more key information.